# Pattern matching IP address extrached from shell command in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I've searched extensively for an answer to my dilemma so I hope someone is able to assist.
I'm trying to retrieve an IP address from a Linux based system then display the IP address on the screen with Python - here's what I have so far:

```
import tkinter
import subprocess
import os
import re
pattern = re.compile("^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$")
test = "10.11.10.1"
cmd = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig eno1", shell=True)
cmd = cmd.decode()
cmd = cmd.splitlines()
ip = re.match('[0-9]+', cmd[1])
if ip:
    print(ip.group(0))
```

If I print(cmd) after the decode is prints several lines of output from the ifconfig command, the second line contains the IP address I'm after so this information is displayed if I `print(cmd[1])`.
If I substitute test for cmd[1] the script prints "10" as expected
If I change the pattern matching line to read

```
ip = pattern.match(cmd[1])
```

I get the same result, however if I change it to

```
ip = re.match(".*", cmd[1])
```

it prints out the same thing as does `print(cmd[1])` so why does it match .* but neither characters or numbers? Is it possible that the raw data is in some other format than ascii??

Comment: Does `ip = re.search('[0-9]+', cmd[1])` work as expected?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, yes it does.  I apologise for duplicating a previous question, I guess this is because I was not looking for the difference between re.match and re.search.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: It is OK, I was in your shoes some 8 years ago.